# Can there be a race condition between calling a 'Get Rule' function and retaining the result?

Tags: objective-c

If a function follows the 'Get Rule' (as outlined by Apple here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-SW1)

Can the result be dealloced (because of a CFRelease else-where) before you have the chance to call CFRetain?

Take the following code for example:

```
// Using CFAttributedStringGetString as an example
// but I am asking about *any* GET rule function

CFStringRef * str = CFAttributedStringGetString(...);
CFRetain(str);
```

Can we potentially be holding a reference to a freed CFString by the time we actually can call CFRetain? If not, why not? How can I avoid this from happening if it's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this code:

```
CFStringRef * str = CFAttributedStringGetString(...);
CFRetain(str);
```

It's impossible to be holding a dangling reference to a `CFString` object.

This is because:

1. Each thread has its own stack and `str` is on that stack and therefore private to the thread, so no other thread has a reference to the string object.
2. The auto-release pool cannot have been emptied as that only occurs between iterations of the runloop and as you haven't returned from that method yet, you have yet to complete that iteration of the runloop.

Comment: Ok, so `str` is on the stack, and private to the thread, and can't be modified, but what it points to *can* be modified in another thread. I understand that a runloop is a single thread, and so no other functions can modify the referenced object until after this function returns, but what about *other* threads?